# Exponentiation - I can do this?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

Euler showed that:

$$
e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0
$$

So I thought:

$$
b \in \mathbb R,i = \sqrt{-1} \\
n^{bi} = e^{bi\ln n}\\
b = 2k\pi\\
e^{bi\ln n} = e^{2k\pi i\ln n} = (e^{i\pi})^{2k\ln n} = ((-1)^2)^{k\ln n} = 1
$$
I'm not sure that all operations are valid.

Comment: What is the question? If the chain of equalities actually holds? Please clarify and edit accordingly.

Comment: I want to know if the operations are valid, and entail : $$n^{bi} = 1$$